# mediawiki project missing in GitHub data?

Tags: google-bigquery

I was wondering why I can't find the mediawiki repository in the GitHub open data collection.

It seems it does have a GNU license?
https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/master/COPYING

Answer (score 0):

Turns out [wikimedia/mediawiki](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki) doesn't have an open source license that GitHub can detect:

[image]

Compare how the license is displayed for [other projects](https://github.com/apache/airflow):

[image]

Docs on how GitHub detects a license:

- https://developer.github.com/v3/licenses/